My java application using jpackage gets error: Failed to launch JVM
Im trying to create a Java app in Intellij with Maven and jpackage. The .jar file is created correctly and it works and the installer seems to be okay, but when I try to open the app that I got from the installer it opens an error window saying Failed to launch JVM. I created the installer using the Intellij interface and the command: jpackage --input target --name kata7 --main-jar kata7-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --main-class org.example.Main --type exe and neither of them works.
This is my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>kata7</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>jpackage</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>--input</argument>
                        <argument>./target</argument>
                        <argument>--name</argument>
                        <argument>kata7</argument>
                        <argument>--main-jar</argument>
                        <argument>${project.name}-${project.version}.jar</argument>
                        <argument>--main-class</argument>
                        <argument>org.example.Main</argument>
                        <argument>--type </argument>
                        <argument>exe</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I read in other posts that this could be related to different versions of jdk in my computer but I checked the environment variables, the version im using in the project and the one used to make the build with maven, its version 18 in every one of them. I really dont know what to do to fix this, hope someone can help me.

You normally need supporting software for Windows, such as Wix >= 3.0. You have that installed?

Pass --win-console when creating the installer, install the application, then launch the installed application from the terminal. You should see the error preventing the application from launching. If you don't want to have to install the application before being able to run it, then you can just create the application image (i.e., --type app-image).

Note the error is unlikely to be caused by multiple versions of Java being installed, since the JRE used by your application is being bundled with said application. Having Wix 3+ installed or not is also unlikely to be related. If that software wasn't installed then you wouldn't even be able to create the installer; plus, Wix is no longer involved after the installer is created.

@Slaw, got it about Wix thanks. Plus, interesting about --win-console. Would there be a case for `always using it just in case?

@g00se Haven't tested it, but I believe passing --win-console will result in a console always being used, with one being opened if the application is not launched from a console. So, I wouldn't pass it for GUI applications. Though it's a good debugging technique on WIndows (especially if you're not already logging to a file, or if the crash prevents logs from being written).
